# Add a background in video editor

Tags: transparency, video-sequence-editor, compile

I have an image strip with transparent background. How can I add color in the background while compiling it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

[image]

Important for the image strip:

Change the blend mode to something like alpha over:

[image]

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot it really worked. However I rendered an image strip again with transparent background. Somehow blender made the background black. Maybe I did something wrong or this is something new in blender 2.93.5. But Is there any solution now, so that I dont have to render all over again

Comment: If this helped you, please check the checkmark left to my answer. Since this is a new question, please ask a new question here. And it is always a big help if you provide your blend file.

Comment: Thank you, I checked it and will ask a new question with the blend file provided

Comment: Thank you very much